# Is it possible to cancel or clear a notification created by using notify-send?

Tags: bash, scripts, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

So I wrote a little script that makes sure a certain user plugs in a laptop when he logs on (it disables if he doesn't). The script uses notify-send to tell him to plug it in. If he plugs it in, the script quits. Is it possible to clear the notification automatically when he plugs it in? I'm thinking it might require somehow getting the process id spawned by notify-send and killing that PID, but I don't know how to do this.

Here's the current script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
OUTPUT="$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
if [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Charging" ] || [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Unknown" ]; then
    echo charging or full
elif [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Discharging" ]; then
    notify-send -i /home/evamvid/Documents/Programming/OokiNoUse/power25.png "Hey there brother" "plug it in"
    COUNTER=0
while [ "$COUNTER" -le 12 ]
do
    cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
    OUTPUT="$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)"
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
    if [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Charging" ] || [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Unknown" ]; then
        exit
    elif [ "${OUTPUT}" = "Discharging" ]; then
        COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))
        echo $COUNTER
        sleep 1
    fi
done
fi
```

Comment: Can you post your current script?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/evamvid/a7231fca5e549d88871e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process you are looking for is `notify-osd`. You can kill it by either the command:

```
pkill notify-osd
```

or by its pid:

```
kill $(ps -e | grep notify-osd | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

or, even better, as suggested by @kos (thanks!), using `pgrep`:

```
kill $(pgrep ^notify-osd$)
```

Comment: It's working in a new Terminal instance, so I guess that somehow the former is corrupted, altough I can't see how! Anyway nevermind, I don't want to clutter your post further, I'll remove my comments (upvoted you answer of course)

Comment: @kos I *did* have an odd thing btw. I even removed the answer at first because I got the message "I didn't have permission" (although it worked...) after a restart it worked fine.

Comment: @kos WOuld you mind if I borrowed your `pgrep`? option? Is actually better...

Comment: Not at all, go ahead :) yes I've got the same message at first but I it was when I wrongly killed `fsnotify_mark` instead, perhaps you were testing using `[...] | grep notify | [...]`?

Comment: For me, using xfce, the process was not named `notify-osd` but instead `xfce4-notifyd`, more specifically `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd`.  I could instead do `pkill xfce4-notifyd` and it would kill the existing notification.  The next time notify-send ran, it auto created the xfce4-notifyd process again, so it seemed safe.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, if you do not want the notification to show up in the notification [history at all](https://superuser.com/questions/351188/how-to-clear-balloon-popup-from-bash), you can try:

```
notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "Title" "Body"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mint MATE 17  The process is listed (example)
15107 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/mate-notification-daemon/mate-notification-daemon

I tried pkill as
`$ pkill mate-notification-daemon`
and even
`$ pkill mate-notification`
And did not work.  However, if I truncated the 'notification' word, it worked:
`$ pkill mate-notificati`
Adding the 'on' to the word makes it not work.  Don't know why.  I imagine
this would pertain to Ubuntu MATE editions as well.

Answer (score 0):

For xfce desktop(Lubuntu 18.04) notify-send:

```
pkill xfce4-notifyd
```